# Function calls subfunction to meet conditions

Tags: python, function

1. If the len() of the input is less than 10 characters then the subfunction 'tester' default value "Too short." is called.
2. Elif the input is 10 or more characters it prints the input.
3. Else if the user input == "quit" the program is terminated.

My following code works to a point. I need help so that the user can input again and again until they type 'quit' at which it simply terminates
and no output is given in the terminal. Pass and continue didn't work and I'm confused where to put a break.

I'm trying a while true, with returns, but I can't follow along anymore.

```
def tester(givenstring = "Too short"):
    if givenstring == 'quit':
        print("quit successful")
    else:
        print(givenstring)

def main():
    prompt = input("Write something (quit ends): ")

    if len(prompt) >= 10 or prompt == 'quit':
        tester(prompt)
    else:
        tester()        
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the default if condition isn't met I simply added a new parameter 'p'. The loop stops immediately in the main function when asked.

Thanks all for your help and answers they really helped. Very cool to see.

```
def tester(p,givenstring = "Too short"):
    result=len(p)
    if result>=10:
        print(p)
    else:
        print(givenstring)

def main():
    while True:
        prompt=input("Write something (quit ends): ")
        if prompt=="quit":
            break
        else:
            tester(prompt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
prompt = input("Write something (quit ends): ")

if prompt == "quit":
    quit()
elif len(prompt) < 10:
    print("Too Short!")
elif len(prompt) >= 10:
    print(prompt)
```

If you really want a second function, you can try this:

```py
def quit_func(givenstring):
    if givenstring == 'quit':
        print("quit successful")
        quit()

def main():
    prompt = input("Write something (quit ends): ")

    quit_func(prompt)

    if len(prompt) < 10:
        print("Too Short!")
    elif len(prompt) >= 10:
        print(prompt)      
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a loop to your main function and break out of the loop when the keyword is found, like this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        prompt = input("Write something (quit ends): ")

        if len(prompt) >= 10 or prompt == 'quit':
            tester(prompt)
        else:
            tester()

        if prompt == 'quit':
            break
```